# How to pass userid from one method to another in mvc3 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am working on a project in MVC 3. How do I pass the user_id of user from one method to another.
Here is what i tried:

```
 public ActionResult ResetPasswordCode(string resetcode, int userid)
    {
        resetcode = Request.QueryString["code"];
        userid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
        var resetuser = _accountUserService.GetAccountUserByResetPasswordCode(resetcode);
        if (resetuser == null)
        {
            if (_accountUserService.SaveResetPasswordCode(resetcode, userid))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", new { resetCode = resetcode, userid=userid});
            }
        }
        else
            ViewBag.ResetError = NcMessage.NotAcitvated;
        return View("Error");
    }
```

ResetPassword method returns the view which allows user to reset their password.
Now the problem i am having is in sending the user_id to a new method that updates the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing in mvc3 there are `Actions Methods` not `Methods`

You can try using `TempData`

In `ResetPasswordCode` action

```
TempData["userid"]=userid;
```

Then in `ResetPassword` action access this using

```
   var userId=(int)TempData["userid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variables

```
Session["userid"] = userid;
```

for retrieve

```
var userid = (int)Session["userid"];
```

or if they are in the same controller you can use static variables, so after your controller definition

```
public static int userid;
```